# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to convert an integer value if I put `intval()` error again come

```
<?php
    $last = $this->db->select('pt_id')->order_by('pt_id',"desc")->limit(1)->get('patient_details')->row();
    //$myvar = (int)($last);
        print_r($last);
    ?>
```

Comment: Try this `$myvar = (int)($last->pt_id)`

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward. $row appears to be an object of type stdClass, which can't be converted to an int.... so stop trying to.

Comment: The `print_r($last);` should have shown you some output. Add that to your question

Comment: @user11044740 your welcome :)